# How to call a function from another page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

So I have a call a timer function on pressing the login  button in the main file. The timer function is defined in the login verification file.  So how can I call the timer function in main file so that when the login button is pressed and when it goes to the login verification the timer starts?

Comment: From what I understant, if you have a function in another file, you should import this file in the main file using the `import` keyword

Comment: You could use voidCallback or function object.

Comment: I have imported the file in to the main file but it is not working

Comment: I have to add the function in onPressed(); . It is not working ,I have also tried voidCallback with type def.

Comment: use import, if your function static, you call it inside static. if not, use instance to call it

Comment: @BhavikDalal this is why you should _show us what you have tried_ in the body of the question with an [edit]. It is a waste of people's time for you to say "I've tried that already" in a comment. Help us help you by telling is what you want to do, showing what you have tried, and showing what results you get.

Comment: @clvrmnky sorry for the inconvenience. But I have mentioned in a comment below that the problem is I cannot share the code and I have tried my best to elaborate the question and I am new to the community, but the problem here is community is not just very welcoming. And when I had posted a snippet with the question someone flagged me for posting code and image  and now when I have not posted a photo people do not like that also. And the thing is I had tried that after posting the Q , I cannot just sit and wait to gets answers I also have to try  some things for faster results.

Comment: @BhavikDalal this is why I reminded you to [edit] the question and put your details in there. Please take the [tour] if you have not already to see why SE sites are not like threaded forums. Q&A is lightly curated, and comments are not part of the Q&A. If you provide a code example it must be as formatted text. This isn't a terrible thing to ask. You can [edit] your question at any time to clarify based on the comments you are getting. Like I said: help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use some parent's function in child widget then it is easy - just pass the reference to the function you want through the constructor.

If you want to use some child's function in parent widget then the situation is a little bit different - you have to pass a GlobalKey to identify the state of child widget when creating an instance of this widget. You can refer to this https://stacksecrets.com/flutter/how-to-call-method-of-a-child-widget-from-parent-in-flutter.

If you want to use a function from a widget that is not either a child or parent widget, then you might think of using some state managment solution (such as Provider or GetX or Bloc) to provide it to all the widget that needs some information from it.

Comment: I do not have to use the parent function in child widget. I have to use a function that is defined in another file and have to use it in the main file. I have to call the function when the login button which is basically a elevated button is onPressed.

Comment: Just include this file in your main file and call this function. If this function is a part of another class then you have to firstly instantiate an object of that class on which you can call the method you want. If that function is marked as "static" than you can call it without instantiating object. Without the real code I'm unable to grasp what the problem might be.

Comment: I am working on a project for a company and unfortunately I cannot upload the code from the project, so sorry for the inconvenience.
I will try your approach.